# Does paperclip in rails only allow square images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

Paperclip for rails only has square images like the following ?

```
  styles: { large:"800x800>", medium:"300x300>", thumb:"150x150#"}
```

I want to change to

```
   styles: { large:"800x740>"}
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use your custom size. Paperclip's `#` option will do exactly what you want. It fits the image maximally within the specified dimensions then crops the excess with gravity at the center.

```
styles: { large:"800x740#"}
```

Comment: am I supposed to restart my server? I have done what you said and it's not responding

Comment: yes, restart your server, and try to upload new images. It will be applicable on images uploaded afterwards